# Thread sequence running in the Java event-driven model

Tags: java

I'm self-taught Java and I'm learning about event-driven programming in Java. I found a very good source code to learn about event-driven, however I am confused about the execution of the program. Here is the code I simulated hybrid from program, hope someone help me.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

interface AA {
}

class AB implements AA {
}

interface BB<K extends AA> {
  public void dispatch(K message);
}

class CC implements BB<AB> {
  @Override
  public void dispatch(AB message) {
  }
}

class DD extends CC {
}

class EE extends AB {
}

class FF extends AB {
}

interface GG<X extends AA> {
  public void registerChannel(Class<? extends AB> contentType, BB<? extends AB> channel);

  public abstract void dispatch(AB content);
}

class HH implements GG<AB> {
  private Map<Class<? extends AB>, CC> handlers;

  public HH() {
    handlers = new HashMap<Class<? extends AB>, CC>();
  }

  @Override
  public void registerChannel(Class<? extends AB> contentType, BB<? extends AB> channel) { //(3)
    System.out.println("EX 1: " + contentType.getSimpleName());
    handlers.put(contentType, (CC) channel);
    System.out.println("EX 2: " + handlers.get(contentType).getClass());
  }

  @Override
  public void dispatch(AB content) {
    System.out.println("EX3");
    handlers.get(content.getClass()).dispatch(content);
    System.out.println("EX4");
  }
}

public class Test7 {

  static Map<Class<? extends AB>, CC> map;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HH hh = new HH();
    hh.registerChannel(EE.class, new DD() {      // (1)
      @Override
      public void dispatch(AB content) {      // (2)
        System.out.println("EX5");
      }

    });
    System.out.println("EX6");
    hh.dispatch(new EE()); // (4)
  }
}
```

And this is the result of the program's execution

```
EX1 EE
EX2: class test1.test1.Test7$1
EX6
EX3
EX5
EX4
```

I wonder why when method (1) is called, method (3) is done but it skips method (2) and continues the program until method (4) is called then the method (2) start execution. And the value of "EX2" is not class so what does it mean? I will be very happy and appreciate if someone give me explanation or any suggestions, sample code. Thanks very much

Comment: What you're looking at is essentially a "call back" or "observer".  This provides a means by which you can be notified of some "event" at some point in the future.  So, when you call `registerChannel`, you pass a new instance of `DD` to it.  This gets stored in the `HashMap`.  When `dispatch` is called, it looks up the callback (keyed by the class) and calls the `dispatch` method.  This is also part of polymorphism

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation, I will dig into polymorphism. Thanks very much